# SharePoint Plus 4.0 whoami "Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am migrating some code from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 that uses jquery and a library called SharePoint Plus 4.0 however I am getting an error in 2010 that I do not get in 2007.

The library docs can be found here:
https://sharepointplus4.netlify.com/people.html#whoami

If I try to use the example code for the "whoami" API

```
$SP().whoami({url:"http://my.si.te/subdir/"}, function(people) {
  for (var i=0; i < people.length; i++) console.log(people[i]+" = "+people[people[i]]);
});
```

Then I get "Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference" error inside the API on this line:

```
var name=data[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Ok it looks like the response is coming back as a 404 in sharePoint 2010 but in my SharePoint 2007 the request is exactly the same is working fine.

Request:

Comment: Have you examined the AJAX response to make sure you have valid XML to work with in the first place?

Comment: So the request is returning a 404

Comment: Well, there you go. Completely different problem.